# IBM Content Navigator JSONResultSetRow Format based on Values

Tags: java, dojo, ibm-content-navigator

I'm writing a Plugin for Content Navigator. It implements a Custom Search and the result contains Folders and Documents.

Now I would like to change the format of rows containing a Folder. They should get a different background color.

Is it possible to add a css class or a formater to the JSONResultSetRow?
How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot apply decorator there. What you have to do is to implement a response filter and there you can apply your style to each row. If you have samplePlugin code from IBM, then look for SamplePluginResponseFilter class.